# How to Create the Same Data for Each Row via SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Query 1:

```
SELECT Color FROM table1;
```

Result:

```
Color
------
red
blue
white
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT Fruit FROM table2;
```

Result:

```
Fruit
-------
apple
pear
banana
grape
```

How do I script to get every color for every fruit?

Need result to look like this:

```
Color  Fruit
---------------
red    apple
red    pear
red    banana
red    grape
blue   apple
blue   pear
blue   banana
blue   grape
etc...
```

I don't know what to do.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Seems like you are looking for a CROSS JOIN.    Select * from Table1 Cross Join Table2

Comment: Please post what you have tried so we may assist you in fixing it.

Comment: Thanks to John Cappelletti, I believe a CROSS JOIN works !!!!!!!!!!

Select * from Table1 Cross Join Table2

THANK YOU SO MUCH !!!!

Comment: There is clear cut problem in table design.Why there is no relation between these 2 tables ?This is so easy.Above all why everyone forcibly trying to achieve output ?

Answer (score 2):

When asking a question it's helpful to provide your DDL/DML as an easily reproducible script, something like:

```
DECLARE @Colours TABLE (Colour VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @Colours (Colour) VALUES 
('red'), ('blue'), ('white');

DECLARE @Fruits TABLE (Fruit VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @Fruits (Fruit) VALUES 
('apple'), ('pea'), ('banana'), ('grape');
```

This enables potential answerers a quick way to set up demo data, and focus on answering your question.

Using that:

```
DECLARE @Colours TABLE (Colour VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @Colours (Colour) VALUES 
('red'), ('blue'), ('white');

DECLARE @Fruits TABLE (Fruit VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @Fruits (Fruit) VALUES 
('apple'), ('pea'), ('banana'), ('grape'); 

SELECT Colour, Fruit /* #1 */
  FROM @Colours c
    CROSS JOIN @Fruits f;

SELECT Colour, Fruit /* #2 */
  FROM @Colours c
    INNER JOIN @Fruits f
    ON 1 = 1;

SELECT Colour, Fruit /* #3 */
  FROM @Colours c
    CROSS APPLY @Fruits f;
```

All three of these queries will produce the result set:

| Colour | Fruit |
| --- | --- |
| red | apple |
| red | pea |
| red | banana |
| red | grape |
| blue | apple |
| blue | pea |
| blue | banana |
| blue | grape |
| white | apple |
| white | pea |
| white | banana |
| white | grape |

#1 and #3 are basically the same, with slightly different syntax. #2 is a Cartesian product, and probably not the best solution.

Comment: `ON 1=1` will be optimized away, so the plan will be exactly the same in all three cases.